# insert a table record into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert a table record into another table. I am selecting user id ,date and variance. When i insert the data of one user it works fine but when i insert multiple records it gives me an error of `SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect time value: '841:52:24.000000'`.

```
insert into 
features.Daily_variance_of_time_between_calls(
uId,
date,
varianceBetweenCalls)

SELECT 
    table_test.uid as uId, 
    SUBSTRING(table_test.date, 1, 10) as date ,
    VARIANCE(table_test.DurationSinceLastCall) as varianceBetweenCalls #calculating the vairiance of inter-event call time

    FROM
    (SELECT
        id,m.uid, m.date,
        TIME_TO_SEC(
            timediff(m.date, 
            COALESCE(
                (SELECT p.date FROM creditfix.call_logs AS p 
                    WHERE 
                        p.uid = m.uid 
                    AND 
                        p.`type` in (1,2)
                    AND
                        (p.id < m.id AND p.date < m.date ) 
                    ORDER BY m.date DESC, p.duration 
                    DESC LIMIT 1 ), m.date))
        ) AS DurationSinceLastCall,
        COUNT(1)
    FROM
        (select distinct id, duration, date,uid from creditfix.call_logs as cl ) AS m

    WHERE 
        m.uId is not NULL
    AND 
        m.duration > 0
#   AND
#       m.uId=171
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ) table_test 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

If i remove the comment it works fine for one specific user.

Comment: Please look closely at your data. Error suggests that the output of your `SELECT` statement is incompatible and will be truncated especially the time part

Comment: Change comment with `--` instead of `#`, I think it's causing an issue.

Comment: @Suraz No issue of commenting its still giving me the same error.

Comment: You are getting rows of invalid time value as `841:52:24.000000` so please check this in the table and correct it and try it again.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi I have the same table structure that select is constructing.

Comment: @Suraz What is the meaning of invalid time value? I don't have time in my table at all. I have three columns uId,date,varianceBetweenCalls

Comment: @FaizanAhmad . . . What are the data types of the columns?  Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: It looks like one of your calculated durations (perhaps). Does the select run if you remove the insert part from the top?

Comment: @SteveLovell yes the select statement run fine if i remove the insert part

Comment: @GordonLinoff datatype for uId is INT, date is DATE and for varianceBetweenCalls is VARCHAR

Comment: Okay, that's good. I'd thought perhaps `TIME_TO_SEC` was running into problems with some of your data. My guess now is that it relates to a bit of bad data in your `date` field (at least when looking at the first 10 characters). You might want to try the select on it's own with an extra line in your `WHERE` clause: `SUBSTRING(table_test.date, 1, 10) = '841:52:24.'` or perhaps `... like '841%'`.

Comment: @SteveLovell  date not like '841%' AND table_test.DurationSinceLastCall not like '841%' it worked for me. I still don't know whats going on!! but now my records have been inserted into the new table of the database.

Comment: That where clause excludes the 'bad' data that caused the insert to fail. If you run the select on its own (and remove the NOT) you'll retrieve the bad data. I'll make a fuller response as an answer later.

Comment: @SteveLovell ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the error message:

> Data truncation: Truncated incorrect time value: '841:52:24.000000'

This message suggests that at some stage MySQL is running into a value which it cannot convert to a `date/time/datetime`. Efforts in isolating the issue should therefore begin with a focus on where values are being converted to those data types.

Without knowing the data types of all the fields used, it's difficult to say where the problem is likely to be. However, once we knew that the query on it's own ran without complaint, we also then knew that the problem had to be with a conversion happening during the insert itself. Something in the selected data wasn't a valid date, but was being inserted into a date field. Although dates and times and involved in your calculation of `varianceBetweenCalls`, `variance` itself returns a numeric data type. Therefore I deduced the problem had to be with the data returned by `SUBSTRING(table_test.date, 1, 10)` which was being inserted into the `date` field.

As per the comments, this turned out to be correct. You can exclude the bad data and allow the insert to work by adding the clause:

```
WHERE
table_test.date NOT LIKE '841%'
AND table_test.DurationSinceLastCall NOT LIKE  '841%' -- I actually think this line is not required.
```

Alternatively, you can retrieve only the bad data (with a view to fixing it), by removing the `INSERT` and using the clause

```
WHERE
table_test.date LIKE '841%'
OR table_test.DurationSinceLastCall LIKE  '841%' -- I actually think this line is not required.
```

or better

```
SELECT *
FROM creditfix.call_logs m
WHERE m.date LIKE '841%'
```

However, I'm not sure the data type of that field, so you may need to to it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM creditfix.call_logs m
WHERE SUBSTRING(m.date,10) LIKE '841%'
```

Once you correct the offending data, you should be able to remove the "fix" from your `INSERT/SELECT` statement, though it would be wise to investigate how the bad data got into the system.

Comment: i have tried this above statement
`SELECT *
FROM creditfix.call_logs m
WHERE SUBSTRING(m.date,10) LIKE '841%'`
but it does not give me any record.

Comment: Perhaps it is the DurationSinceLastCall after all ... which still seems odd to  me. What is retrieved when you do the original select (without the insert) but using `WHERE table_test.date LIKE '841%' OR table_test.DurationSinceLastCall LIKE  '841%'`

Comment: it gives me an empty table

Comment: Will probably need to move to chat at some stage here ... I'm now very confused. Is the following summary correct? : (1) code (including insert) fails "as given". (2) Code (including insert) succeeds when `WHERE
table_test.date NOT LIKE '841%'
AND table_test.DurationSinceLastCall NOT LIKE  '841%'` is added. And (3) Code (without the insert) returns no rows when instead we add `WHERE table_test.date LIKE '841%' OR table_test.DurationSinceLastCall LIKE '841%`

Comment: That's pretty weird. I'll have to give it some thought. Anyone else got ideas?

Comment: What happens (without insert) if you use `WHERE table_test.date is NULL AND table_test.DurationSinceLastCall is NULL`? If that finds rows, does the insert work if you exclude those using `WHERE table_test.date is NOT NULL OR table_test.DurationSinceLastCall is NOT NULL`?